# Concatenating Strings When Using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

How can you do stuff like `SetWindowText( static_label, "I know this thing" + myString )` ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `static_label`.

Comment: Is there anything in your question that is not answered by [the `SetWindowText()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) ? Are you asking how to concatenate two strings *during* a call to `SetWindowText()` (thereby making the actual call completely irrelevant)?

Comment: Also, it is not clear what operator overloading has to do with calling a function.

Comment: Did you mean to do `SetWindowText( static_label, "I know this thing" + myString)` ? Note the difference in the location of the quotation marks. If so, what is the **type** of `myString`? Is it a `CString`, an `std::string`, `char*` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <atlstr.h>

CString a = "I know this thing ";
CString b = "foo";
SetWindowText(static_label, a + b);
```

Comment: Doesn't `CString` require MFC? @Psychoman did not say whether or not he is using MFC.

Comment: CString does not require MFC.

Comment: If you can do this stuff with CString without MFC , then it's what I wanted thx.

Comment: @Psychoman, Looks like there is still a dependency on using ATL. You can do it with `std::string` without having have it depend on anything other than the standard C++ libraries.

Answer (score 6):

This question has nothing to do with operator overloading, or overloading in general for that matter.

If you are referring to how `SetWindowText (...)` can be used to set the title for a dialog window and a static label it is because `HWND` is a generic handle.

If on the other hand, you are asking how to concatenate text, you can use a `std::string` and call `.c_str (...)` to get a null-terminated string that the Win32 API wants.

Comment: One can also provide define an overload of `SetWindowText` that calls `c_str()` for you and then calls the Win32 version.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using only the standard C++ libraries (and obviously the Windows API). It's a little more complicated than using `CString` ([ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library)) though. However, if you plan on releasing your code as Open Source, this method would probably be better since it will allow others to compile the code using compilers other than Visual C++ (e.g. [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/)).

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

HWND static_label;

int main() {
    // ...
    std::string a = "Hello ";
    std::string b = "World!";
    std::string c = a + b;
    SetWindowText(static_label, c.c_str());
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Another way without having to use `b` or `c`

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

HWND static_label;

int main() {
    // ...
    std::string a = "Hello ";
    SetWindowText(static_label, std::string(a+"World!").c_str());
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```